# how to ensure only unique values in dropdown

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I've got a drop down with a bunch of values and some of them are dupes:
[image]

```
                        <label for="AAAPurposeType_AAAPurposeType" class="bl-label bl-text-align--left">
                            <%=Html.Encode(Model.AAALoanType.DisplayName)%></label>
                        <div class="data width-70"><%=Html.EditorFor(m => m.AAALoanType)%></div>
```

How do we display ONLY unique values?

Comment: how are you getting your option values? if it's an array, you can convert it to a set then make it an array again, then display the text. Using 'Set' is a good and easy way to guarantee that you dont have duplicate values

Comment: What is the source for the dropdown values? Can you not pre-process them?